# changing WordPress Front page to another script front page without changing WordPress posts Permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress setup in home "public_html" and the articles Permalink is a post name like this "www.website.com/post-name" and I want to install a service script "TruelySell" in the website in a new folder like "public_html/services" but I want the service script front page to be the front page of the website [www.website.com/](http://www.website.com/) without changing the WordPress posts urls.
I tried to do it with .htaccess but WordPress keep changing .htaccess file every time I touch the WordPress settings

is there any solution to make this possible?

TL;DR: WordPress and a service script on the same website, and trying to make the service script on the front page of the website without changing the WordPress posts links

Comment: _"but WordPress keep changing .htaccess file every time I touch the WordPress settings"_ - WordPress overwrites the part of the .htaccess between the `BEGIN WORDPRESS` and `END WORDPRESS` comments, whenever you flush the permalink settings. If you want to make your own additions to this file that survive beyond that - then you need to put them _outside_ of that block.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to do it with `.htaccess` but WordPress keep changing `.htaccess` file

Because you are putting the rule in the wrong place. You should not manually edit the code in the WordPress code block (ie. between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers) - as the code comment before this code block should state.

Your rule would need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
# Rewrite requests for "homepage" to "/services/" subdirectory
RewriteRule ^$ /services/ [END]
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Note that you need to include the trailing slash on `/services/`, otherwise mod_dir will issue an external redirect and expose the `/services` subdirectory in the URL.

However, you should really be rewriting to the actual script that handles the request, eg. `/services/index.php`, not simply `/services/` - which requires mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for the `DirectoryIndex`.